# Convert improper fraction to mixed number - Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, floor

I am trying to write a program that does multiple things to an array of fractions. I started working on the Fraction class first which contained the various methods that would do things to the fractions. One of these tasks I am trying to accomplish is converting the fraction into a mixed number. Here is what I have so far:

```
public String toMixed(int numerator, int denominator){
    String mixedNum;
    int wholeNum;
    wholeNum = Math.floorDiv(numerator,denominator);
    mixedNum = wholeNum + (numerator - wholeNum*denominator)/denominator;
    return mixedNum;
}
```

While logically this draft of this method makes sense to me, there is an error in my draft that I overlooked. I cannot convert an int value to a String value the way I have in this code.

So what I am looking for is help modifying this method to get it to return the String mixed number that I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is the best practice but what I usually do to convert into int to string is to append any string to it. Anyway, I modified one line in your code and let me know if this is what you are trying to achieve.

`mixedNum = wholeNum + " " + (numerator - wholeNum*denominator) + "/" + denominator;`

`toMixed(9, 5)` will result to 1 4/5

Comment: Alright, so I have the program finished and this method worked into it, and yes this works, but there are a couple things I'd like to clean up. If there is no whole number in the mixed number I don't want it to display a zero, and the same goes for the fraction (no zeros). Secondly, it currently outputs for a negative mixed number with a "-" in front of each number in the mixed number (Example: -5 5/6 is returned as -5 -5/-6)

Comment: For your first problem check first if numerator is greater than the denominator. If yes, do your logic as usual. If no, then just create a string value of the fraction.

Comment: For the second problem, you have to specify where you put the negative sign. Better yet, add a parameter for  the sign so you only have to deal with whole numbers